# dimple.js - place axis label above shape

Tags: dimple.js

To avoid messing with truncation or rotation of axis labels on row charts, I'm trying to place the label over the row itself where there is lots of space. I've managed to do the SVG transform to move the label over, but it is below the box itself in terms of z-index.

I cannot use CSS z-index to re-order SVG components, and the boxes are all in the same `<g>` as the axes themselves (but not grouped in their own child `<g>`) which seems to make re-ordering difficult.

Any suggestions on how to get the labels above?

[image: Shifted axis label]

Answer (score 0):

dimple renders most of the elements into a single `<g>` element as you have noted.  Since all of the elements are simple dom elements you can use something like jquery to remove the elements and then re-add them after the rest of the elements in the `<g>` since svg elements render in the order of the dom elements.

see https://api.jquery.com/detach/.

I've got a pull request for dimple where I add more `<g>` elements to hold things apart.

you might do something like

(pseudocode)

```
label = $('svg label').detach();
$('svg').append(label);
```

This should put the label at the end of the svg contents which means it would be rendered over the rest of the content.